# converting velodyne packets to pointcloud

Tags: ros, pcl, pcl-conversions, velodyne, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hii,
I have velodyne packets and its config file . I want to convert it to point cloud in a C++ program. Can anyone provide me API to do this .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261061/converting-velodyne-packets-to-pointcloud/) by [shashank](https://answers.ros.org/users/25836/shashank/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2017-05-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

here is the api to convert into pcl data structure .After this we can use Pcl_conversion to convert the cloud into sensor_msg::pointcloud2

```
    #include "velodyne_pointcloud/calibration.h"
    #include "velodyne_msgs/VelodynePacket.h"
    #include "velodyne_msgs/VelodyneScan.h"
    #include "velodyne_pointcloud/rawdata.h"
    #include "velodyne_pointcloud/point_types.h"
    #include "velodyne_pointcloud/VelodyneConfigConfig.h"
    #include "velodyne_pointcloud/point_types.h"
    #include  "velodyne_pointcloud/calibration.h"
    #include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>

void save_3d_lidar(velodyne_msgs::VelodyneScan::ConstPtr v_scan,nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr gps_pose)
{



    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI> cloud_3d;
    pcl::PointXYZI point;
    velodyne_rawdata::RawData data;

    cloud_3d.clear();

    for(int i=0;i<v_scan->packets.size();i++)
    {
        pcl::PointCloud<velodyne_pointcloud::PointXYZIR> v_point_cloud;
        
        
        data.setParameters(0.9,130.0,0.0,6.28);
        data.setupOffline("file adresss",130.0,0.9);
        data.unpack(v_scan->packets[i],v_point_cloud);
       
        for(int j=0;j<v_point_cloud.size();j++)
        {

            point.x=v_point_cloud.points[j].x;
           
            point.y=v_point_cloud.points[j].y;
            
            point.z=v_point_cloud.points[j].z;

            point.intensity=v_point_cloud.points[j].intensity;
            cloud_3d.push_back(point);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Originally posted by [shashank](https://answers.ros.org/users/25836/shashank/) with karma: 70 on 2017-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [velodyne_pointcloud](http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne_pointcloud) package does what you seem to need.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2017-05-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shashank](https://answers.ros.org/users/25836/shashank/) on 2017-05-04**:
Not exactly...I do not want  to run a node for that.I am looking for a library to do it.Basically I need a function in which I give velodyne scan as input and it gives me point cloud as oputput

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2017-06-12**:
It's not exactly an advertised interface, but I suppose you could use the RawData class: http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/velodyne_pointcloud/html/classvelodyne__rawdata_1_1RawData.html